# Fullscreen triangle pass and texcoords

Tags: directx11, hlsl

So I have a fullscreen triangle shader like this:

```
#ifndef FULLSCREEN_TRIANGLE_VERTEX_HLSL
#define FULLSCREEN_TRIANGLE_VERTEX_HLSL

// Variation on Timothy Lottes FXAA vertex shader, for CCW frontface
float4 vs_main(uint VertexID: SV_VertexID) : SV_Position
{
    return float4(float2(((VertexID << 1) & 2) * 2.0f, (VertexID == 0) * -4.0f) + float2(-1.0f, 1.0f), 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

#endif
```

This helps me during deferred shading, since I can just do like this in the pixel shader:

```
float4 ps_main(float4 position : SV_Position) : SV_Target0
{
    float ssao = 1.0;
    if (gUseSSAO)
    {
        ssao = gSSAOTexture[uint2(position.xy)].r;
        ssao = (clamp(1.0 - (1.0 - ssao), 0.0, 1.0) + 0.1) / (1.0 + 0.1);
    }

    return gDiffuseTexture[uint2(position.xy)] * ssao * gAmbientLight;
}
```

SV_Position automatically gives me the screenspace position of the pixel.
Now some of my alghorithms require texture coordinates. I know this is simply `(screenspacePosition.xy / textureSize.xy)` but I want to avoid those instructions in my pixel shader. Is there some system-provided value (like SV_Position) or any neat way to enhance the fullscreen vertex shader to provide me with texture coordinates aswell?

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this, so no divide in the PS. Vertex Shader code follows:

```
struct VertextoPixel
{
    float4 pos              : SV_POSITION;
    float2 tex              : TEXCOORD0;
};

VertextoPixel main(uint vI : SV_VERTEXID)
{
    float2 inTex = float2(vI%2,vI%4/2);
    VertextoPixel Out = (VertextoPixel)0;
    Out.pos=float4((inTex.x-0.5f)*2,-(inTex.y-0.5f)*2,0,1);
    Out.tex=inTex;
    return Out;
}
```

Comment: the divide that he had will be optimized in the pixel shader, as it's a constant

Comment: @babis: Are you sure? I have to pass in the texture size as a uniform, it is not a constant value

Comment: Sorry, morning confusion, I was talking about the divide by  "1/ (1.0 + 0.1)" which might be a bit irrelevant as Janos was probably talking about the divide that you would have to do to get the UV.

Comment: Janos, if bitwise ops are supported you can change the inTex calculation to float2 inTex = float2(vI&1,vI>>1) which is much faster, if it's not automatically optimized that is.

Comment: Yeah good point, I am just not used to those. :)

Comment: The texcoords are wrong are they not? the Y-range I get is from 1.0 (top, should be 0.0) to 0.5 (bottom, should be 1). Likewise X-range is 0.0 to 0.5? Do you have a fullscreen quad maybe? since I'm using a triangle. Btw Im using CCW too so perhaps thats why its not correct?

Comment: Oh, so you have one triangle for the whole screen? I meant I am creating a quad with two "full-screen" triangles (that's the usual way of doing it). That code will not work for a single triangle, sorry. :(